# Texture problem, color is off in some places?

Tags: texturing

I dont understand why the textures are different here? Its the same texture and no matter what I try the spots are much brighter. Im relatively new to blender so am I missing something?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EggV3.jpg

EDIT:Sigh I just cant get this screenshot function to work on this site. So the link is a screenshot. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Looks like your normal map is bad.

Comment: Thanks it seems really like the normal was at fault. I got it from textures.com so I didnt even thought of that possibility, tried another and the spots are gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that normal map is wrong space (not tangent space).